# Validate and check Time with Combo Box content

Tags: vb.net

I've got an array that stores times in string format "10:00" the cboTime combo box shows the content of the array.

I want to validate the time selected for that I don't want users to select a time from cboTime that had already passed in the system time clock.

However, I don't get the results I want and the code doesn't operate the way it should and I don't know why.

Please see the code below and I would be very happy with a solution to this problem.

```
Public strTimeRoomsEvents() As String = {"10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", "15:00", "16:00", "17:00"}

    cboTime.DataSource = strTimeRoomsEvents


    If dtpBookDate.Value > Today Then
        valid_time = True
    ElseIf dtpBookDate.Value = Today And DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString < cboTime.SelectedItem Then
        valid_time = False
    Else
        valid_time = True
    End If
```

Comment: 1. `dtpBookDate.Value.Date = Today`, 2. Do not validate strings for time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems with using strings for times and dates is that the strings can vary according to the computers settings, so it is best to avoid things like "ToShortDateString" unless they are being used to *display* the data.

I assume that you want to check for validity when either the date or the time is changed, and that you didn't intend that dates earlier than today are valid. The other problem is in the clause `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString < cboTime.SelectedItem` - have another look at it and think about what that is comparing.

I put the controls you mentioned on a form and a Label to show the status:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub InitBookingTimes(startHour As Integer, endHour As Integer)
        Dim startTimes = Enumerable.Range(startHour, endHour - startHour + 1).Select(Function(h) $"{h:00}:00").ToList()
        cboTime.DataSource = startTimes

    End Sub

    Private Sub dtpBookDate_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dtpBookDate.ValueChanged
        Label1.Text = IsValidBookingTime(dtpBookDate, cboTime).ToString()

    End Sub

    Private Sub cboTime_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboTime.SelectedIndexChanged
        Label1.Text = IsValidBookingTime(dtpBookDate, cboTime).ToString()

    End Sub

    Function IsValidBookingTime(dateSource As DateTimePicker, timeSource As ComboBox) As Boolean
        Dim rightNow = DateTime.Now

        Dim validTime = True
        Dim proposedDate = dateSource.Value.Date

        If proposedDate <= rightNow.Date Then
            Dim proposedTime As TimeSpan
            If TimeSpan.TryParse(CStr(timeSource.SelectedValue), proposedTime) Then
                Dim proposedDateTime = proposedDate.Add(proposedTime)
                validTime = proposedDateTime > rightNow
            Else
                ' Could not parse time portion, so assume it is invalid
                validTime = False
            End If
        End If

        Return validTime

    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        InitBookingTimes(10, 17)

    End Sub


End Class
```

The purpose of passing references to the controls to the `IsValidBookingTime` function is that you can use the same function with other controls, e.g. you might want to do the same with a pair of controls for booking-out time.

Comment: _use the same function with other controls_ - even better instead of controls, pass values, then you will be able reuse this function anywhere.

Comment: @Fabio Or even betterer, add an overload which takes values, then there would be no need to repeat the value extraction code. But we're not expected to provide production-quality code here, and the intention was to give the OP an idea of what *could* be done.